# Why does two grounds vs one ground give different results in LTspice with rectifier circuit?

Tags: ac, ground, rectifier

Here is my circuit (full  wave rectifier).

I have tried make it exactly as I saw on the internet, but it's not working.

The voltage I am measuring is \$V_{R_1}\$

The real breadboard also showed me the  same strange stuff as LTspice:

[image]

If I put ground in different place as in the second picture it works as expected:

[image]

[image]

With two grounds we have a half wave rectifier:

[image: Two Grounds]

This is what I measured in the lab with an oscilloscope:

[image]

Using Two channels will not make it work.
two channels are basically overlapping with each other. You will not see any difference between each of them.
[image]

However, it works perfectly with two channels in simulation.
[image]

Comment: So, what do you think the problem is?

Comment: @Andyaka I think the software has a bug? Can you give me hints?
I am also building this on breadboard with Arbitrary Function Generator as a source. I gave almost the same result as LTspice.

I think the problem is either the Arbitrary Function Generator or Osillscope.

Comment: @kile No it doesn't have a bug. Do the math on your circuit. Can you draw how currents flow and how the currents cause voltages on resistances?

Comment: If you solved your own problem, please edit that out of the question and put it as an answer instead. You can accept your own answer and the question will appear as solved in the system.

Comment: Ground is the reference point for all voltage measurements so, having it at two vastly different points will produce vastly differing measurements. Ground is not earth; it's a node you nominate that makes sense for where you want 0 volts to be.

Comment: @Andyaka In reality, I can only do the first simulation, which  will give me unsuccessful result. How can I make it work as expected? And what's worse, my poor uni doesn't have differential probe.

Comment: Then you cannot use a bridge rectifier if you have two grounding points because you are shorting out diodes. This is not a suitable application for a bridge rectifier.

Comment: @Andyaka Is there a way for me to measure the voltage across Resistor $$R_1$$ directly with oscilloscope?

Comment: Use two channels and use the subtract function you might have as a feature in your oscilloscope.

Comment: @kile In this particular circuit, you could have also done the second ground measurement by using an isolation transformer to disconnect the first ground.

Comment: @Andyaka Two channels don't work as expected!!! They are overlapping with each other

Comment: Use the subtract function.

Answer (score 1):

Current flows between grounds once they are added. If you want to see what this would be like, remove one of the grounds and place a very low value resistor like a 10mΩ between the two nodes (while one ground is removed), this will enable you to measure the current.

Basically what is happening is you are shorting the nodes together and current is flowing to the short and not through the diodes. (kind of like shorting D4, but you are also shorting D4 and R2)

Comment: I don't have current probe for the oscilloscope. What should I do then? How can re-design the circuit for it?

Comment: Why would you need a current probe? Don't ground both sides

Comment: Yes, I removed the ground now. The only ground I keep now is the source.

Comment: Yep, then you aren't shorting the diode

Comment: What current are you talking about? I am confused. How can I measure current without current probe?

Comment: What are you trying to measure?

Comment: The voltage across the resistor $$R_1$$

Comment: You use two probes, one before and one after and then subtract